# How to change text of each DIV class indivdually?

Tags: sql, html, while-loop

I am loading multiple DIV from Database

That my Javascript for click

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {

    var role = 0;
$(".role").click(function(){
   if(role == 0) 
   {
       role = 1;
       $(".role").text("Decision Approver");


   }
    else if(role == 1) 
    {
        role = 2;
          $(".role").text("Decision Maker");


    }
    else if(role == 2)
    {
        role = 3;
          $(".role").text("Influencer");


    }
    else if(role == 3)
    {
        role = 4;
          $(".role").text("Gate Keeper");

    }
    else if(role == 4)
    {
        role = 5;
          $(".role").text("User");

    }
    else if(role == 5)
    {
        role = 6;
        $(".role").text("Stake-holder");

    }
    else if(role == 6)
    {
        role = 0;
        $(".role").text("");

    }


});
});

</script>
```

my CSS for the DIV "role"

```
{
position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 min-height:20px;
 height:auto;
 border:1px solid #000; 
 word-wrap: break-word; 
 float:left;
 font-size:12px;
  z-index: 30;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:3px;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
$qry = "SELECT * from contact";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    <div class="role" align="center"  ></div>
}
```

Multiple DIV has been generated, when I click on one DIV role, all the DIV role change their text. How can I change each DIV individually and update them to database by contactID?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use jQuery to do this client-side (and on this assumption I've no idea what the SQL is doing in either the tags or the question) I'd suggest using an array to contain the new text:

```
var textValues = ['Decision maker', 'Decision approver', 'influencer']; // and so forth

$('.role').text(function(i){
    return textValues[i];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f3Q98/1/).

The above will iterate over each of the `.role` elements, the `i` represents the index of the current element (amongst those other elements in the collection), and will set the text to that contained at the `i` position within the `textValues` array.

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Is it possble to do  onclick for DIV?

Comment: like <div class="role" align="center" onclick="clicked(this);" id="'.$row["ContactID"].'"></div>

Comment: Yes, obviously. Just use the relevant selector. And, also, the `align` attribute is deprecated/obsolete. Use `auto` for the left, and right, `margin` in CSS instead. For a *useful* answer show your relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are updating the role, all conditions are met one after the other, so you need to include return false; that is similar to break;